# How to expose an image folder and access them via a route?

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-7

I have a list of flags located at :

`/home/bheng/app/public/assets/be/img/flags/`

```
...

-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  4655 Apr 29 16:34 tf_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3024 Apr 29 16:34 td_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  5379 Apr 29 16:34 tc_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  5316 Apr 29 16:34 sz_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3486 Apr 29 16:34 sy_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  4902 Apr 29 16:34 sx_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3508 Apr 29 16:34 sv_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3986 Apr 29 16:34 st_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  4290 Apr 29 16:34 ss_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3765 Apr 29 16:34 sr_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3856 Apr 29 16:34 so_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3580 Apr 29 16:34 sn_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  4959 Apr 29 16:34 sm_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3077 Apr 29 16:34 sl_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  4483 Apr 29 16:34 sk_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3517 Apr 29 16:34 sj_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 robot robot  3483 Apr 29 16:34 si_64.png
drwxr-xr-x 2 robot robot 12288 Apr 29 16:34 .
┌──[robot@world]──[/home/bheng/app/public/assets/be/img/flags] 
└──
```

[image]

I want to load that image when I visit

```
https://www.bunlongheng.com/flags/*
```

Ex.

```
https://www.bunlongheng.com/flags/sn_64.png
```

I've tried add this line to my nginx

```
location ^~ /flags/ {
    root /home/bheng/app/public/assets/be/img/flags/;
}
```

I still get 404 on my URL : `https://www.bunlongheng.com/flags/sn_64.png`

What did missed?

---

## Also

I've tried `alias`

```
location /flags/ {

    alias /home/bheng/app/public/assets/be/img/flags/;
    #root /home/bheng/app/public/assets/be/img/flags/;
}
```

Comment: there are two options: first, you can put them in storage and with storage:link, second: you can use webpack for copying assets from resources/assets/images to public/assets/images.

Comment: How can I make it work without relocating the folders? My entire project structure around `/assets/` already and would like to keep it that way.

Comment: Note if I put the complete route works : https://www.bunlongheng.com/assets/be/img/flags/si_64.png

Comment: it is not a standard way, if you look at laravel all of them follow those solutions. If you have CI/CD the only thing you need is just copying from assets to public without need to change nginx configuration.

Comment: for local dev, you can also use symlink!

Comment: If I copy. Then I will have same data in 2 places

Comment: you have something in assets you push it on git and when you want to deploy it on production you will copy it. so it's not important that you have two places!

Answer (score 1):

You need `rewrite` instead of `alias` :

```
location ~ /assets/be/img/flags/(?<filename>.+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /flags/$filename last;
}
```

or another way maybe you should use root:

```
location ~ /flags/ {
    root /assets/be/img/flags/;
}
```

but both ways need to use `php artisan storage:link`, because it's must be a public nginx path.

Comment: I like 2nd one, 404 still https://www.bunlongheng.com/flags/si_64.png